# if-statement with elem results in wrong output

Tags: haskell

I have written a program whose purpose is to replace/extend every consonant characters in a given word with the constonant itself, an 'o' and the constonant following. If the character is a vocal, the program should ignore it and move on.

For example, the string "progp" should result in "poprorogogpop".The only vocal in the string "progp" is the 'o' and it should therefore not be repeated. 
This basically means that I want to construct a program which replaces a char with a String.

This is what I have so far:

```
rovarsprak :: String -> String    --Definition of our function which recieves an String as input and returns a String--
isVocal :: Char -> String       --Function which determines if a letter is a vocal or not--

vocals = ["aeiouy"]; --List with relevant vocals--

rovarsprak [] = [];  --Case for empty input--
rovarsprak (x:xs) = isVocal(x) ++ rovarsprak(xs)

isVocal x = if elem [x] vocals
  then [x]
  else [x] ++ "o" ++ [x]
```

If I compile and run this with the input parameter "progp" I recieve:

"poprorooogogpop"

Everything in the output is correct up until the 'o' character in the middle of the sentence in "progp" since the vocal 'o' should not be repeated in that way.

My suspicion is that error lies within the elem-part of the if-statement or that it may be related with the recursion.

A word of notice, I am extremly new to haskell programming and have searched for issues related with the elem-statement but to no success.

Comment: May I ask what book are you learning from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vocals` is intended to be a `String`, not a `[String]`:

```
vocals = "aeiouy" --List ['a','e','i','o','u','y'] with relevant vocals--
```

`isVocal` would be a good name if it returned a `Bool`; you are actually returning a possibly different string, so something like `consonantToSyllable` would be better.

Notice that it's simpler to just return the correct list of letters rather than building a bunch of short lists and concatenating them.

```
consonantToSyllable x = if elem x vocals then [x] else [x,'o',x]
```

or

```
consonantToSyllable x | elem x vocals = [x]
                      | otherwise = [x,'o',x]

rovarsprak [] = []
rovarsprak (x:xs) = consonantToSyllable x ++ rovarsprak xs
```

The above recursion is the pattern captured by `concatMap`: map a function over a list, then concatenate the resulting lists into one list.

```
rovarsprak word = concatMap consonantToSyllable word
```

or just

```
rovarsprak = concatMap consonantToSyllable
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 errors in your code. First, a String is already a list of characters so `vocals = "aeiouy"` is enough.

Then you can test `elem x vocals`.

Besides, your looping function `rovarsprak` is not tail recursive. `foldl` will make it so, by handling an accumulator in the signature (and it's also clearer that it's a loop) :

```
rovarsprakBis :: String -> String
rovarsprakBis = foldl (\acc x -> acc ++ isVocal x) ""
```

Comment: The definition of `isVocal` also needs to be updated to return a string instead of a list of strings.